# Create Docker connection between containers NodeJS + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

The main task is to run docker on ports and connect to them via localhost.

How it should work:

---

**Service #1** (./service_one/docker-compose.yml)

**NodeJS #1** on port `3001`

**MongoDB #1** on port `27018`

**Node #1** connects to **MongoDB #1** as `localhost:27018` (or default `localhost:27017`)

---

**Service #2** (./service_two/docker-compose.yml)

**NodeJS #2** on port `3002`

**MongoDB #2** on port `27019`

**Node #2** connects to **MongoDB #1** via `localhost:27018` and **MongoDB #2** through `localhost:27019` (or default `localhost:27017`)

---

**NodeJS #1** is available via `http://localhost:3001/`.

**NodeJS #2** is available via `http://localhost:3002/`.

**MongoDB #1** is available via `localhost:27018`.

**MongoDB #2** is available via `localhost:27019`.

---

The current state of the configuration is:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  node-users:
    container_name: node-users
    command: "npm start"
    depends_on:
      - mongo-users
    expose:
      - 3001
    image: node:10.9.0
  mongo-users:
    container_name: mongo-users
    expose:
      - 27018
    image: mongo:4.0.1
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: user
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: user
    hostname: mongo-users
```

And second one.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  node-auth:
    container_name: node-auth
    command: "npm start"
    depends_on:
    - mongo-auth
    expose:
    - 3002
    image: node:10.9.0
  mongo-auth:
    container_name: mongo-auth
    expose:
    - 27019
    image: mongo:4.0.1
    ports:
    - 27019:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: auth
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: auth
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: auth
    hostname: mongo-auth
    # network_mode: host won't work on docker for Mac!!!
    network_mode: host
```

Very strange, but there is no intelligible tutorial how to do it.

Update.

In example I want to connect to **MongoDB #1** from **NodeJS #1**.

My connection string will be:

`mongodb://user:user@mongo-users:27017/user`

Which works perfectly. But when using it from **NodeJS #2** there is no way to reach `mongo-users` because `network_mode: host` fails on Mac (and ok on Windows or any Linux). So my containers just don't work on other people computers.

`failed to connect to server [mongo-users:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo-users mongo-users:27017]`

I tried to use `bridge`, create network. But none of solutions is work for me.

Comment: What is the question here? Did you manage to run the containers and the node project successfully or are you getting an error?